# Amazon EC2 Bitnami Wordpress Leverage Browser Caching

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, cache-control

Just setup a Wordpress site on an using an Amazon EC2 Bitnami AMI. I've ran the usual suspects of speed tests and have added this to my .htaccess file, like I've done dozens of times before:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

However I still get the issues around saying I should leverage browser caching. Apache has restarted and even the server has been rebooted but same happens. I've checked the Apache2 config file and the mod_expires module is present (I'm 99% sure it is!)

Anything I'm missing that is maybe specific to Amazon EC2 and/or Bitnami Wordpress?

Standard Bitnami AMI... Linux version 3.13.0-100-generic

Comment: The most obvious problem to check for is whether mod_expires is installed and enabled.   That is going to depend on which image you installed on your EC2 instance.   Different Linux distributions have different ways of installing and configuring Apache modules.

Comment: The standard Bitnami AMI... Linux version 3.13.0-100-generic. Also  expires_module is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two things you need to check.

First edit `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and make sure that the line loading mod_expires is not commented out (comments start with `#`).   If it is, uncomment it and restart Apache.  ([source](/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf))

If you are trying to set the expires headers in *.htaccess* you will also have to allow overrides in your Apache configuration.   Edit *httpd.conf* and make sure that `allowoverride all` is specified.  ([source](https://community.bitnami.com/t/cant-get-mod-expires-to-work-on-an-ec2-bitnami-image/26905))

Comment: This is not commented: LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so. Also allowoverride all is specified. Apache restarted. Nothing